# (ApexCharts) How can I make the pie chart the same size?

Tags: charts, legend, apex, apex-code, apexcharts

**My Problem** : Chart size is fixed including legends.

I want to fixed pie chart size except legends.
How can I make the pie chart the same size?

This is my code.
Help me plz

```
var options = {
          series: [25, 15, 44],
          chart: {
            type: 'pie', 
            **width: '300px'**
        },
        labels: ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday"],
        theme: {
          monochrome: {
            enabled: true,
            color: '#f38200',
            shadeIntensity: 0.9
          }
        },
        plotOptions: {
          pie: {
            size : "200px"
          }
        },
        stroke: {
          show: false
        },
        dataLabels: {
          enabled: false
        },
        legend: {
            position: 'bottom',
            horizontalAlign: 'left',
            markers: {
                width: 9, height: 9
            },
            itemMargin: {
                horizontal: 20, vertical: 0
            },
            formatter: function(seriesName, opts) {
              ~~~~~~~
              return legend;
            }
          }
        };
```

[IMG - This is my problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KE1zi.png)

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the legend width or height to a static value, e.g.

```
legend: {
  width: 200
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using -

```
legend: {
  floating: true
}
```

and setting the legend's position using offsets.